# Equivalence of solutions in min and max optimization problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let us consider the following optimization problem:

for fixed $y$ ($y$ can be vector, possible from compact set) find $x$ such that

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{maximize}}
& & f_0(x,y) \\
& \text{s.t.} & & f_i(x) \leq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m\\
& & & h_i(x) = 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, p
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Assume there is another function $g_{0}(x, y) \neq f_0(x,y)$ such that for any fixed $y$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \text{argmax}_{x}f_{0}(x, y) = \text{argmin}_{x}g_{0}(x, y),\\
& \text{s. t. }\,\,\,\,  h_i(x) = 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, p
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

The question: when the following would work for any $y$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&  \text{argmax}_{x}f_{0}(x, y) = \text{argmin}_{x}g_{0}(x,y) \\
&  \text{s. t. } \,  f_i(x) \leq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m\\
&    h_i(x) = 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, p
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
given some conditions imposed on $f, g, f_{i}$ and $h_{i}$ (linearity, differentiability, convexity etc.)?

Comment: $$g_0(x,y) = -f_0(x,y)$$ or am I missing something?

Comment: Dear skr, oh.. I see, but this is a trivial solution... The question is that if functions' 
actively constrained solutions are the same, could it be possible (under some conditions) that the same would be with extra non-active constraints? Of course, that would be the case if inequality constraints do not affect the estremum.